# VAR lag selection tests: Which one do I choose?

Tags: model-selection, aic, vector-autoregression, bic, lags

When running `varselect` in R, I usually get a few different models to choose from based on different statistics. I know of:

1. Akaike information criterion (AIC)
2. Bayesian information criterion (BIC) or Schwarz criterion (SC)
3. Final Prediction Error (FPE) criterion
4. Hannan–Quinn information criterion (HQC)

What is the practical difference between these tests and under what circumstances should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: See Lütkepohl ["New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis"](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540401728) (2005), Section 4.3 "Criteria for VAR Order Selection", it gives a thorough discussion. Trying to summarize it here would be quite some work, though, but I hope you can access the original – it is pretty readable and clear. See also ["AIC,BIC,CIC,DIC,EIC,FIC,GIC,HIC,IIC — Can I use them interchangeably?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86767/aic-bic-cic-dic-eic-fic-gic-hic-iic-can-i-use-them-interchangeably?rq=1) for AIC, BIC, and HQC; FPE is not covered there, though.

Comment: Just a curiosity: for a paradox involving AIC vs. BIC, see ["Paradox in model selection (AIC, BIC, to explain or to predict?)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177391/paradox-in-model-selection-aic-bic-to-explain-or-to-predict?rq=1).

Comment: @RichardHardy awesome.

Comment: I think Lütkepohl's books is great, and the paper by Galit Shmueli too (each in its own way)!

Answer (score 1):

Monte Carlo evidence suggests that the BIC penalty function works well in designs calibrated to macroeconomic data ([Stock and Watson, 2011](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Emwatson/papers/Stock_Watson_HOM_Vol2)). It is common to run them all for comparison purposes.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please add full reference in case your link dies in the future. Thanks