# Information criteria to select best Prophet model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prophet, information-criteria

How do you optimize your hyperparameters when using prophet for forecasting? I have been using cross validation and I don't know why no information criteria (such as AIC or BIC) has been implemented into the package.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don’t see AIC or BIC for Prophet because it is a Bayesian model, while AIC and BIC are about the likelihood. For Bayesian model you would rather use [WAIC or DIC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86767/aic-bic-cic-dic-eic-fic-gic-hic-iic-can-i-use-them-interchangeably), or cross-validation.